# Do-while won't work

Tags: c++

My loop doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a,b,c;
cin >> a >> b;
do
{
    c=a-b;
}
while(c>=b);
cout << c;
}
```

When I input 5 and 3 it worked but when I tried inputting a larger number like 61 and 3 it doesn't work. There's no output.

Comment: [Doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins133991.html), are we? If `a - b >= b` the first time round, it will stay that way, no matter how many times you evaluate the same condition.

Comment: Did you forget to assign `c` value to `a`  or `b` after subtraction ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
c = a - b;
```

every iteration, without ever changing `a` or `b`. So in you second example, `c` always equals `58` which is greater than `b == 3`, so the loop will never exit.

Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to fix this because you did not say what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks :) I fixed it now

Comment: @Camz No problem. Please note that "Thank you"-comments are against the rules on SO. Instead, you can accept the answer that you deem most helpful by clicking the checkmark next to it. Once you have enough reputation, you can upvote any post.

Answer (score 0):

Insert line 'cin >> a >> b;' into loop do-while. If not the loop has not sense and you should to change it by a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Values of a, b, c are not changing no matter how many times the loop gets executed. In cases wherein  c (a-b) is greater than or equal to b, the loop never exits. That's why you are not getting output for a = 61 and b = 3.